# citations with biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, citing, texstudio, biber

I'm trying to make citations work with my .bib file.
Right now I don't quite know how to proceed further. I got some experience with Latex, but have no workflow with citing yet.

I would like to use biblatex with biber, particularly because I'm studying linguistics.

I have created a .bib file via zotero and placed it into the path
/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/

Currently I'm switching to vimtex and I succeeded compiling stuff from nvim but as an insurance I first want to make citing work with my old workflow, hence Texstudio...

Please excuse my ignorance and telling a whole life story here...

My example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
citestyle=authoryear
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references1.bib}

\cite{de_swart_philosophical_2018}
\title{life is life}
\author{halem}
\begin{document}
    Text some more text...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Move command `\cite` after `\begin{document}` ...

Comment: ofc! no errors left. 

but it doesn't print the bibliography and doesn't cite, it only displays the naked citekey when compiling...

Comment: You need to follow the compiling chain: pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex ...

Comment: Do you mean print via terminal? I just press F6 +F7. Sorry, I have no clue...

Comment: Sorry, I do not use TeXstudio, I do not know what F6 and F7 do. Use the terminal for testing purposes and check later, what you have to do in TeXStudio ...

Comment: OK thanks for the instruction. In the terminal,
I ran pdflatex once and then biber twice. 
this is what I get...

https://gist.github.com/tjallemaal/fbfa96c3c7d4c1fe7e49bd95ce54f46d

Maybe it's the underscores in my citekey... no idea really

Comment: @Fran: Nice! I was aware of most of the steps except the printing part. I falsely typed "biber test.tex" instead of "biber test"
I've read multiple times that sometimes some fiddling is necessary, e.g. deleting aux files etc.
my noob journey continues :)
thanks also to Mensch